Android Apk vulnerabilty given by MobSf
I'm uploading my APK to MobSF for a security scan, and it's flagging a vulnerability:
(androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity) is not protected. [android:exported=true]. An Activity is found to be shared with other apps on the device, making it accessible to any other application.
It seems that BootstrapActivity is an internal activity from androidx.test, and MobSF is detecting it as a potential security issue. The warning suggests setting android:exported="false" in the AndroidManifest.xml to prevent external apps from accessing this activity.
However, AndroidManifest.xml is in read-only mode, so I can’t modify it directly. Since this activity is part of the AndroidX testing library and is not meant to be exposed in the release APK, I’m looking for ways to:
Either modify the manifest file during the build process to ensure android:exported="false" for BootstrapActivity.
Or find a solution to make MobSF pass this warning.
Has anyone else encountered this issue with MobSF or similar tools? Any help on how to resolve this or silence this warning would be appreciated.

"However, AndroidManifest.xml is in read-only mode" -- there are multiple manifests, including writeable ones that you could use to affect this change. The real problem is that this APK contains androidx.test code at all. As the name suggests, this is used for testing, and a production APK generally should not contain test-specific code. Perhaps there is a bug in the way you have set up your Gradle dependencies that is causing androidx.test code to appear in your release APK.

@CommonsWare Thank you for reply so how i can androidx.test code disappear in release apk and mobsf should not detect it?

@CommonsWare Thank you for the help , i have disappear the androidx.test in release mode by adding debugImplementation in gradle dependency and it is working fine.

Usually, test dependencies are set up via testImplementation() (for unit tests) or androidTestImplementation() (for instrumented tests). See the documentation.

@CommonsWare Ok Thank you , i need to ask one more question i am getting a waring from mobsf i.e Broadcast Receiver (androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver) is Protected by a permission, but the protection level of the permission should be checked.
Permission: android.permission.DUMP
[android:exported=true] , can you help me to fix this?

I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, with a [mcve].
